# Jammy not responding

Tags: upgrade

Upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 systematically fails. At the first step "Preparing to upgrade" there is an error message "Jammy is not responding".

[image]

What is wrong?

My network connection is fine:

```
$ ping -c 3 google.com
PING google.com (142.250.74.78) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from arn09s23-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.74.78): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=12.5 ms
64 bytes from arn09s23-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.74.78): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=12.8 ms
64 bytes from arn09s23-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.74.78): icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=12.8 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 12.506/12.687/12.804/0.129 ms
```

The output of `do-release-upgrade` shows several Timeout errors:

```
$ do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                                                                                                                            
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,265 kB]                                                                                                                                                   
Fetched 1,266 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                                  
authenticate 'jammy.tar.gz' against 'jammy.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'jammy.tar.gz'
[sudo] password for v: 

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                         
Get:1 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                                                                                      
Get:2 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]                                                                                                    
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                                                                                                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                              
Hit https://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                           
Hit http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease                                                                                                                
Get:4 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [278 kB]                                                                                     
Hit https://deb.packages.mattermost.com focal InRelease                                                                                                                         
Get:5 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [391 kB]                                                                                 
Get:6 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [944 B]                                                                                
Get:7 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [8,012 B]                                                                                  
Hit https://deb.packages.mattermost.com stable InRelease                                                                                                                        
Get:8 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [30.5 kB]                                                                              
Hit https://repo.fortinet.com/repo/6.4/ubuntu /bionic InRelease                                                                                                                 
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [40.7 kB]                                                                                     
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [77.6 kB]                                                                                
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]                                                                              
Fetched 1,165 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                                  
Error: Timeout was reached
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Error: Timeout was reached
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
None

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

Changing the Ubuntu mirror (via the `Software & Updates` tool) did not help. However, maybe the error message invoked by hitting the <kbd>Refresh cache</kbd> button provides some hint:

[image]

Comment: Run in a terminal `do-release-upgrade` and you'll see what is  wrong. Maybe you have a bad internet connection.

Comment: @Pilot6, I provided the output of `do-release-upgrade` in my question.

Comment: It looks like you have network problems, or the `lv` mirror is having problems. Switch to another mirror.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue because I had a package source in `/etc/apt/sources.list/` that no longer exists. After I removed the invalid source using `sudo vi` I was able to get past this message.